# How to detect change of object property which bind to another object property?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have many nav item. Each of the nav should be visible when the user has appropriate rules. I try like something:

My object which contains a some rules:

```
rules: {
    canSeeProfile: true,
    canSeeAdminZone: false,
    ...
}
```

Also I have an array of navigation items:

```
nav: [
    {title: 'profile', visible: this.rules.canSeeProfile},
    {title: 'admin zone', visible: this.rules.canSeeAdminZone && this.rules.canSeeProfile},
    ...
]
```

My header contains the following template:

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let navItem of nav">
    <li *ngIf=navItem.visible>
        {{navItem.title}}
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

But *ngIf not updating when `rules` variable changes:

```
hideProfile() {
    this.rules.canSeeProfile = false;
}
```

How can I update my template without reiniting my `nav` array? Or, maybe there is a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: each part of the code is part of same component or different component?

Comment: the same component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace your values by functions:

```
nav: [
  {title: 'profile', visible: () => this.rules.canSeeProfile},
  {title: 'admin zone', visible: () => this.rules.canSeeAdminZone && this.rules.canSeeProfile},
  ...
]
```

Then use

```
<li *ngIf="navItem.visible()">
```

Or, if you want it to be slightly more efficient (but more verbose), then emit an event every time the rules change, and recompute every visible value stored in `nav`.